# Nativescript 6 - page.showModal does not work anymore

Tags: nativescript

After migrating my app to NS 6, the modal view does not work anymore.  Here is some code.

main view:

```js
page.showModal('/components/login/login', {
                context: null, 
                closeCallback: (res: boolean) => {
                ... some code
            }, 
            fullScreen: true});
```

The modal view: (code truncated for brevity)

```js
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { Observable } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { Api } from '../../tools/api';
import { LoadingIndicator } from "nativescript-loading-indicator";

var model = new Observable();
var api = new Api();
var loader = new LoadingIndicator();
var page: Page;

var closeCallback;

export function onShownModally(e) {
    page = <Page>e.object;
    closeCallback = e.closeCallback;
    page.bindingContext = model;
}

export function login() {
    loader.show();
    api.login(un, pwd).then((res: any) => {
        loader.hide();
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            closeCallback(true);
        } else if (res.statusCode == 401) {
            closeCallback(false);
        }
    }, (err: any) => { 
        closeCallback(false);
    });
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```html
Argument of type '"components/login/login"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewBase'
```

I also tried using 'app/components/login/login' with no success.

I looked through the documentation and I cannot find what I am doing differently.

Has anyone seen this error?  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of call `closeCallback` directly (which always seam odd to me and look like error in documentation) try to call `page.closeModal(true/false)` (https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page#closemodal).

Comment: I can't even build the project because of the error I am getting.  The issue is in the call to show the modal not the way I am closing it.

Comment: Is it a runtime exception or a static typescript error?

Comment: it is a build error

Comment: That sounds more like a TypeScript compiler issue, but as per the docs and declarations it should work. Try casting it to any (`page.showModal(<any>'/components/login/login', ...`).